# In SSRS ,Is it possible to divide portion of Pie chart again based on some values?

Tags: reporting-services

I have  data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWaGx.png)

Where %ofTotalVoids is  : (TotalVoid of Individual/TotalVoid) *100 and %ofReissued is (Void Reissued for individual/TotalVoid Individual)*100.

I have a chart which shows %ofTotalVoids ,now in this I want to divide Pie chart such that it also shows %Reissued.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JowMD.png)

For example OfficerName Duncan, OfficerId 0000 has % total Void as 42% now again this has 88% as Reissued so I want to divide this portion again.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

In current Reporting Service reports, When using area, column, line, and scatter charts, any combination of these series can be displayed on the same chart area. But it is not available for the pie charts combination.